# Origen y significado de la expresion "patinar las neuronas"?

Tags: modismos

Sólo he encontrado esta referencia (http://argot_es.esacademic.com/4698/patinar_las_neuronas), donde se explica el significado (tener confusión mental, despistarse; decir inanidades) y pone ejemplos («A esos les patinan las neuronas.» ❙ «Te empieza a patinar la neurona con el tema...».).  Como es la unica referencia que he encontrado, no se si es correcta y en todo caso localizo nada sobre su origen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo me guiaría con la acepción 5 de la RAE para [patinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S9rnYDt%7CS9tUqG7):

> 5. intr. coloq. Perder la buena dirección o la eficacia en lo que se está haciendo o diciendo.

Imagino que al decir que las neuronas "patinan" se da la idea de que la persona no está en su óptima capacidad de pensamiento, lo que concuerda con el significado que encontraste sobre confusión mental.
Otra expresión parecida es "patinar el coco". Yo asocio "coco" con la cabeza, y vendría a significar algo similar a la anterior expresión: la cabeza/cerebro no está funcionando muy bien.